# Запись ботом ответа пользователя в переменную

Tags: python, telebot

Хочу что бы бот проверял ответ пользователя на выражение, выдает ошибку.

```
import random
import telebot
import config
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Чтобы начать тренировку сложения целых чисел - /aoi')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['aoi'])
def aoi(message):
    num1 = random.randint(1, 10000)
    num2 = random.randint(1, 10000)
    sum1 = num1 + num2
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str(num1) + ' + ' + str(num2))
    user_result = message.text
    result(message)

def result(message):
    if int(user_result) == sum1:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Верно.')    
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Не верно. Ответ: ' + str(sum1))

    aoi(message)
    
    
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

```
C:\Users\KuznecOFF\Documents\python\math generator>bot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KuznecOFF\Documents\python\math generator\bot.py", line 39, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
  File "C:\Users\KuznecOFF\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1043, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop=non_stop, interval=interval, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
  File "C:\Users\KuznecOFF\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1118, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\KuznecOFF\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1074, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\KuznecOFF\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 147, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Users\KuznecOFF\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 90, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\KuznecOFF\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 6801, in _run_middlewares_and_handler
    result = handler['function'](message)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\KuznecOFF\Documents\python\math generator\bot.py", line 25, in aoi
    result(message)
  File "C:\Users\KuznecOFF\Documents\python\math generator\bot.py", line 30, in result
    if text == sum1:
               ^^^^
NameError: name 'sum1' is not defined. Did you mean: 'sum'?
```

Comment: ты забыл добавить ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Передайте `sum1` в качестве аргумента функции `result`

```py
def aoi(message):
    num1 = random.randint(1, 10000)
    num2 = random.randint(1, 10000)
    sum1 = num1 + num2
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str(num1) + ' + ' + str(num2))
    user_result = message.text

    result(message, sum1) #Тут

def result(message, sum1): #тут
    if int(user_result) == sum1:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Верно.')    
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Не верно. Ответ: ' + str(sum1))

    aoi(message)
```

p.s. логику кода не проверял.

Comment: File "C:\Users\KuznecOFF\Documents\python\math generator\bot.py", line 23, in aoi
    result(message, sum1)
  File "C:\Users\KuznecOFF\Documents\python\math generator\bot.py", line 26, in result
    if user_result == sum1:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'user_result' is not defined

Если по такому же принципу добавить user_result, то бот бесконечно спамит

Comment: @Григоря возьми учебник и почитай о том, как работают функции и переменные в них. Твои ошибки возникают из-за того, что ты этого не знаешь.